# Tool for measuring Real and Reactive Power

Tags: oscilloscope, multimeter, reactive-power, power-measurement, real-power

I am currently doing a project where I need the Real power (P) and Reactive power(Q) measurement for a Refrigerator. 
I understand that if I can measure AC Voltage(V) and AC Current(A) for the Refrigerator, then I can calculate the Power Factor. From that then I can calculate both P and Q.

I want the data to be captured at a frequency of 1 sample/sec.
So, let say if I capture the data for an entire day, then it will be 86400 data points.

Now,
Q1. I was wondering if there is any device/tool/measurement unit that can measure AC voltage and current, or even directly the power and then log that data on some storage device, either USB or WiFi.

Q2. I checked there are multimeters that can be connected to USB and then transfer data to PC, but then how can I measure and log data for both simultaneously using a multimeter?

Q3. Another way is using an oscilloscope. But they are very costly and I am looking for a cheap alternative. Do you know any?

Comment: How are you calculating pf from V & I?  A DMM does not give you phase angle.

Comment: [The engineers that inhabit this site are not shopkeepers or consumer champions working for Which magazine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: My idea was to gather the voltage and current data with timestamps. Then plotting the data on software like MATLAB or something, I can calculate the power factor. Maybe this is a completely bad strategy. But I don't know any better

Comment: I am not asking a buying guide, I just don't know if there is a device that can do the stuff I wanted. That's why asking here.

Comment: So you get 1 sample a second (1Hz) for voltage and current for a 60Hz/50Hz signal.  Does this make sense?  Your approach is wrong.

Comment: Any WiFi mains plug power meter you can buy at the electronics store? Or china, UNI-T has some.

Comment: I know that sampling 60/50Hz data at 1Hz, I will lose a lot of information. But then I also have to think for the storage. Let say if I collect the data at 60Hz, then for a day, I will have 5184000 data points. That is a lot of data. Hence a compromise on the resolution. The Power factor might not be accurate but will be a ball park figure.

Comment: WiFi main plug usually gives only Real Power and then sampling is also quite less. The ones I checked they take reading 1 every minute.

Answer (score 2):

There are power analyzers specifically meant to do exactly what you are looking for.

One product is the Fluke 435 Power Logger: [FLUKE 435](http://www.fluke.com/fluke/m2en/Power-Quality-Tools/Logging-Power-Meters/Fluke-435-Series-II.htm?PID=73939)

Unfortunately these types of products are not "cheap".  It's not a trivial measurement to make, since it's not just a matter of volts/amps/phase angle but harmonic distortion as well.

Another method as you suggest is to log the current and voltage at the same time, and post-process with Matlab.  Then you could just use any one of a bunch of PC data acquisition modules and a current transducer.  This is probably the cheapest solution.  However, your sample rate would have to be several times the highest harmonic that you want to take into account, so maybe a couple of kHz.  You could then have Matlab spit out the real and apparent power at 1 sec intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked that I can use the National Instrument(NI) DAC or DMM for this kind of high-frequency measurement and then use LabView to calculate the power (P and Q) and power factor. But again they are costlier than the Fluke 435. Can you recommend me any DAC?

Comment: I think you want an ADC not a DAC.  I don't know your specs for accuracy, how many harmonics you want to take into account, etc, but a quick Google search gives the following really low cost option for use with a PC.  You could probably make this work, but you will have to dig into the specs to see, I haven't done that: http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?products_id=2521&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5Y-6pq2o2QIVD369Ch37qgMNEAkYBCABEgJEB_D_BwE